# Convert String into an object instance name

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, object, string

I'm trying to turn an string into an instance name.

```
stage.focus = ["box_"+[i+1]];
```

this gives me back = `box_2`;

but I need it to be an object not a string.

In as2 I could use eval. How do I do it in as3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
this["box_"+(i+1)]
```

Comment: +1 in my answer I was adding `.` after this, and deleting my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Dani! that if fact is the correct syntax!

      stage.focus = this["box_"+(i+1)];

Answer (score 2):

For example if you would like to call the function "start" in your main class, you'd do it this way:

```
this["start"]();
```

Same thing goes for variables. Since all classes are a subclass of Object you can retrieve their variables like you would with an ordinary object. A class like this:

```
package{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class Main extends Sprite{
        public var button:Sprite;

        public function Main(){
            trace(this["button"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Would output:

```
[object Sprite]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a member of the current class, the answers already given will work. But if the instance you are looking isn't part of the class, you are out of luck.

For example:

```
private function foo():void {
    var box_2:Sprite;
    trace(this["box_"+(i+1)]);
}
```

Won't work, because box_2 isn't a part of the class. In that case, it is highly recommended to use an array.

If you want to access a DisplayObject (for example, a Sprite or a MovieClip) you also can use [getChildByName](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29). But in that case, `box_2` will be the name of the **object**, instead of the name of the **variable**. You set the name like

```
var box:Sprite;
box.name = "box_2";
```

But again, I recommend an array.

Comment: I do have an array, what I wanted was, that after you typed on box_1, if it was correct, to change the focus to box_2...