# AS3 / TweenLite - How to return an array element as a variable in TweenLite?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, variables, gsap

The code is below.  When Tweenlite is called it treats "tileList[count1]" as a string instead of a variable name.  However the trace seems to return what I would expect (tile1, tile2, tile3...).  If I remove "tileList[count1]" from the tween and replace it with a direct call to the MovieClip (tile1, tile2, etc) the code works perfectly...

```
public class wtpMain extends MovieClip {

    public var tileList:Array = new Array(tile1,tile2,tile3,tile4,tile5,tile6,tile7,tile8,tile9,tile10,tile11,tile12,tile13,tile14,tile15    ,tile16); 
    public var count1:int = 0;


    public function wtpMain() {
        nextButton.buttonMode = true;
        nextDis.mouseEnabled=false; 

        nextButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextButtonClickh);

        tileList.sort(randomSort);

    }

    public function nextButtonClickh(event:MouseEvent):void {
        nextButtonClick();
    }

    public function nextButtonClick():void{


        TweenLite.to(tileList[count1], 5, {y:700, alpha:0});
        trace(tileList[count1]);
        count1++;

    }

    public function randomSort(objA:Object, objB:Object):int{
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 2) - 1;
    }
}

}
```

Thanks!

---added---

Things I've tried:

- Using a vector instead of an array.
- Setting tileList[count1] to a variable and then calling that variable.
- Removing the randomSort.
- Removing count1 and calling the array element directly (ie, tileList[5]).

Comment: Have you tried using a Vector instead of an Array? And what exactly are you trying to accomplish, or rather, why does it concern you how Tweenlite treats Object references?

Comment: I have not tried a vector.  I have 16 "tiles" on the screen and I want them to randomly be removed one by one with each button click.  All of the code works if I replace "(tileList[count1]" with "tile1" or "tile2", but not when I pull the same name from an array.

Comment: That certainly is strange behavior. Out of interest, what type of Object are those tiles? Sprite/Movieclip, or something custom? Something drawn in Flash Pro? As a workaround, you could do the following, in the first line of the function `nextButtonClick` : `var o:Object = tileList[count1]; TweenLite.to(o,5,{y:700,alpha:0});` So you will first get a reference to the object, then use that reference in TweenLite, instead of using it directly in TweenLite.

Comment: The tiles are movieclips.  I tried the Object workaround and got the following error - "Error: Cannot tween a null object.".

Comment: I also tried using a vector - got the same errors.

Comment: How did you create these tiles? Where do they come from?

Comment: They are .png files created in photoshop then added via insert symbol/MovieClip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching I stumbled on [Convert String into an object instance name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371847/convert-string-into-an-object-instance-name)

and got the following solution from it (tested and working!)

```
public var tileList:Array = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16); 
TweenLite.to(this["tile"+tileList[count1]], 5, {y:700, alpha:0});
```